# Modified wave equation

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have some background in differential calculus, but it is not enough. I need to bring this equation

$$\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial x^2} + \frac{1}{x} \frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial x}+ \frac{1}{x^2} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y} - i \frac{x}{z}\right)^2 f(x,y,z) +\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial z^2} + f(x,y,z)=0$$

to the form

$$\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial x^2} + \frac{1}{x} \frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial x}+ \frac{1}{x^2} \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial y^2} +\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial z^2} + f(x,y,z)=0$$

It seems simple, but I have tried several substitutions for $x,y,z$ and it didn't work at all. I am lost!

Comment: I also may be missing something, but it seems to me that going from the first to the second would require $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = i \frac{x}{2z}f$. I suppose you don't have such a condition?

Comment: That would screw up 1st, 2nd and 4th terms, I think, but thanks, I will try.

Comment: Are you meaning some change of variables then? Because as it appears now, the variables have remained the same, and if you subtract the desired equation from the first equation, you end up with the equality written in my first comment.

Comment: Khm, you sure? $\frac{1}{x^2}(\frac{\partial }{\partial y} - i\frac{x}{z})^2 f - \frac{1}{x^2}\frac{\partial^2f }{\partial y^2} = -i\frac{1}{xz}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \frac{1}{z^2} f$

Comment: A bit curious in what application this equation shows up.

Comment: $$\frac 1{x^2}(\frac{\partial }{\partial y} - i\frac xz)^2 f - \frac 1{x^2}\frac{\partial^2f }{\partial y^2} = -i\frac 2{xz}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} - \frac 1{z^2} f$$

Comment: @mathreadler Electrodynamics.